# ruby method call - include argument if statement is true

Tags: ruby, rest-client

Looking for an elegant way to include a method argument if a statement is true. In this case it is a rest-client call, the argument is verify_ssl: FALSE. Below is the code with my last attempt I want to insert verify_ssl if @ignore_cert is TRUE. This is part of a larger class I have created. Thanks in advance!

```
def get_tenant_uid
  JSON.parse(RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get,url: "#{base_url}/tenant",
    headers: {:'X-SDS-AUTH-TOKEN' => @auth_token,
      accept: :json
    },
    verify_ssl: FALSE if @ignore_cert
  ))
end
```

Comment: How about `verify_ssl: !@ignore_cert`?

Comment: no dice, but this did lead to the obvious answer...doh! changed setting from ignore_cert to verify_cert in the config file. Now it is verify_ssl: @verify_cert. Thanks for the mental push!

Comment: I don't understand why `verify_ssl: !@ignore_cert` wouldn't work, but glad to hear you got it working by renaming the variable.

Comment: Got it working by converting to a boolean, twas a string before. !@ignore_cert would have worked. Thanks again!